Convergence on Borel sets implies weak convergence
Let $X$ be a locally compact space and let $M(X)$ denote all $\mathbb{C}$-valued regular Borel measures on $X$. Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset M(X)$ be a sequence. I want to show that $L(\mu_n) \to 0 $ for all $L\in M(X)^*$ is equivalent to $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lVert \mu_n\rVert < \infty$ and $\mu_n(E) \to 0$ for all Borel sets $E$.
One direction follows from Banach-Steinhaus and taking $L_E$ to be the evaluation at the Borel set $E$.
But what about the other direction? In particular, how does the boundedness of the supremum come into play?

I’ll only prove the backward direction here.
Since $\sup_n \|\mu_n\| < \infty$, $\mu = \sum_n 2^{-n} |\mu_n|$ is a finite measure on $X$ under which all $\mu_n$ are absolutely continuous. Thus, there exists $f_n \in L^1(\mu)$ s.t. $\mu_n = f_n\mu$. $\|f_n\|_{L^1(\mu)} = \|\mu_n\|$, so $C = \sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^1(\mu)} < \infty$. I claim that $f_n \to 0$ weakly. Indeed, pick any $g \in L^\infty(\mu)$. Then there exists a simple function $g_0$ s.t. $\|g - g_0\|_{L^\infty(\mu)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2C}$. By taking linear combinations, we see that $\int_X g_0 \, d\mu_n \to 0$, so there exists $N > 0$ s.t. whenever $n \geq N$, we have $|\int_X g_0 \, d\mu_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But then,
$$\begin{split}
|\int_X gf_n \, d\mu| &<\frac{\epsilon}{2} + |\int_X g_0f_n \, d\mu|\\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{2} + |\int_X g_0 \, d\mu_n|\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&= \epsilon
\end{split}$$
whenever $n \geq N$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, this proves the result.
But now, we have $L^1(\mu) \subset M(X)$. For any $L \in M(X)^\ast$, we may then restrict it to $\tilde{L} \in L^1(\mu)^\ast = L^\infty(\mu)$, so $L(\mu_n) = \tilde{L}(f_n) \to 0$.
